# PvZ 2: Charge-up Time at the Beginning of Game

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

I have been playing [Plants vs. Zombies 2: It's About Time](http://www.popcap.com/plants-vs-zombies) for quite a long time now, and I've been watching videos on it even longer. In the videos, I've noticed that at the beginning of the game, the sun-producing plants don't have a charge time. But mine do.

Is this feature an upgrade, an update, or a mechanic that I don't know about?

Also, do any of you have this problem? (I just don't wanna be the oddball)

Comment: You can check the version history [here](https://appsto.re/us/n5iPJ.i)

Comment: Thanks! I found that it was in the later levels where they updated it so that double sunflowers had a charge-up time at the beginning using your link!

Answer (score 3):

It actually depends on the plant.

Sunflowers, sunshrooms, primal sunflowers, moonflowers, and gold blooms can all be planted immediately. Twin sunflowers, sunbeans, and toadstools each have a charge time before they can be planted.